# Nrwl for Angular: Customizing generated stories

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I am generating stories using Nrwl for Angular for my re-usable Angular component library. It seems by default it generates stories with capability where user can change inputs to the components and see the impact of that input.

Q: How to add code snippets to these stories so that if any developer wants to use a component, they know what code they need to write to implement a component. I just want them to copy and paste and start using the compoennt.

Something like this:

https://5ccbc373887ca40020446347-eiwjaghawn.chromatic.com/?path=/story/codesnippets--single

Btw how they are creating this snippet, where is `<CodeSnippets` component ?